# When picking a train test split for model training, does it choose an even number of samples from all class?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, testing, training-data

Let's say I have a CNN model to classify the handwritten numbers 1 to 10. I am using a dataset with 20,000 samples and I make a train test split of 50:50.

That leaves me with 10,000 for training and testing. Will, it automatically pick 1000 images from each class for testing/training, or will it approximate it?

I am trying a similar problem, (with different numbers of samples and classes) but I noticed that the testing data is not evenly split. For example, it has 1010 number ones being tested but only 990 number twos.

Is this normal? I couldn't find any documentation verifying this. My dataset is large enough that the small discrepancy is irrelevant, but I still would like to confirm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The test train loader will approximate the split, since it uses sampling with replacement each epoch to generate a test batch.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know if it's possible to specify to use an even number from each class during a split?

Comment: One way to do it is to replicate the data loader functionality yourself to a more deterministic implementation instead of random sampling